# Python/shell scripting for loop on aapt.exe d badging eachAPKName.apk

Tags: android, python-3.x, shell

I am new to Shell Scripting. Could you please help me to write code for below requirement? I tried using for loops but it did not work.

1. I have Folder "ApkFiles" and It has 100 .apk files
2. I need to run the below commands on all those .apk files in the folder

   ```
   echo nameOfEachApk >> minTarget.xls
   aapt.exe d badging eachAPKName.apk | grep -E 'sdkVersion|targetSdkVersion' >> minTarget.xls
   ```

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will iterate over the directory the python folder is located in. Simply put this in a .py file in your apkfiles directory and run it. I can't test it since I don't have your exact setup but it should do what you are asking.

```
from subprocess import call
import os

# Get current working directory
cwd = os.getcwd()

# Get a list of files in the current working directory
f = open("minTarget.xls")
for apkFile in os.listdir(cwd):
    # These call commands will run the shell commands you need
    # The [:4] strips off the .apk from the file string
    call(["echo", apkFile[:-4], ">>", "minTarget.xls"], stdout=f)
    call(["aapt.exe", "d", "badging", apkFile, "|", "grep", "-E", "'sdkVersion|targetSdkVersion'", ">>", "minTarget.xls"], stdout=f)
f.close()
```

To see how an explanation of how I am calling the shell commands look at the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the time. It is working perfectly except the output of those two lines of code, under the for loop, is not moving into minTarget.xls file. It is just displaying in the terminal itself.

Comment: I edited the code to pipe the stdout to a file called minTarget.xls. I think that should do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for making changes, but it's still not greping and dumping output to text file. Thank you!